# Node MongoDB Native - filter by date/time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In native MongoDB, the following limits my full text search to articles published in the past 6 hours:

```
db.getCollection('articles').find({
    $and: [{
        $text: {
            $search: 'stackoverflow'
        }
    }, {
        $where: function() {
            return Date.now() - this.published.getTime() < (6 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        }
    }]
})...
```

The above does not work on Node.js with [node-mongodb-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) - the whole $where object is ignored, but doesn't throw an error. Is there any other way I can limit my query results based on time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating the datetime object prior to using it in your query by constructing a new Date with the value of the current timestamp minus 6 hours as follows:

```
var sixHours = 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000; /* ms */
    sixHoursAgo = new Date(new Date().getTime() - sixHours);

db.getCollection('articles').find({
    $text: { $search: 'stackoverflow'},
    published: { $gte: sixHoursAgo  }
})
```

Or you could use the **[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/)** library which is pretty handy when dealing with dates, in particular the [**`subtract()`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) method

```
var moment = require('moment'),
    sixHoursAgo = moment().subtract(6, 'hours');
```

Comment: Great solution. I notice there is no `$and` operator - is it not necessary?

Comment: @FrancisKim It is not necessary because it becomes an implicit AND operation when you specify a comma separated list of expressions, like the above. Using an explicit AND with the [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.